# Py4JError: An error accurred while calling .saveAsTable

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to train linear regression using spark. I have a loop in which I train the model 9 times, on the first pass the cycle processes and proceeds to the second model. at the moment:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('name_table')
```

python gives an error:

`Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o2254.saveAsTable`